# Getting an (x, y) -> depth map in Python from a Kinect?

Tags: python, kinect, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm going around in circles trying to solve what I think is a simple problem: using Python (not C++), I would like to get the depth values corresponding to the points in the RGB image returned from the Kinect at a given (x, y) coordinate.  I am subscribing to /camera/rgb/image_color and using cv_bridge and OpenCV's face detector to get the bounding box around a face.  I then want to get the depth values for each point (or a subsample of points) in that box.  So I need to be able to pick (x, y) coordinates (which I know) from within the box and get back the depth values for those points.

I tried subscribing to /camera/depth/image which is a 32FC1 image type and I thought this was going to work but I ran into "index out of range" errors when accessing points that should have been within the proper width and height boundaries of the image.

Although I realize there are no Python bindings for PCL )-:, I found [this nice utility](http://answers.ros.org/question/213/is-there-a-python-equivalent-of-fromrosmsgtorosmsg) on this forum so I'm wondering if I should be using point clouds rather than images to get the depth values?

Any ideas?

Thanks
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10084/getting-an-(x,-y)--%3E-depth-map-in-python-from-a-kinect?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2011-05-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-05-28**:
OK, when I look more closely on a higher resolution image I can see it is not perfectly rectangular.  Also it looks like my script was converting NaNs to 0's.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-05-27**:
No, I get mostly NaNs at the border. But it's not like a rectangular frame, because of the lens distortion.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-05-27**:
Thanks Felix--see my answer below.  BTW, do you get a black border (all 0's) around your depth image?  It looks to be about 5 pixels on a 160x120 image.

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-05-27**:
"I tried subscribing to /camera/depth/image which is a 32FC1 image type ... but I ran into "index out of range" errors" - that's weird. In c++ this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to Felix's comment, I went back to the /camera/depth/image approach and finally realized I was swapping rows and columns in one of the statements which is why I was getting "index out of range errors".  So repeat after me: an image that has m X n pixels has n X m rows and columns. :-)

--patrick

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2011-05-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/5130/ros/) on 2013-06-12**:
hello I want to subscribe to rgb and depth image simultaneously and publish it to multiple topics using one node in cvbrige, plz plz can u provide me ur code, I m in trouble